# how to map ctrl + p to ctrl + space on vim sshd using mac terminal

Tags: linux, macos, vim, terminal

Im using a mac terminal to ssh into a remote linux server.

For autocompletion in vim, the default key combo is `ctrl + p`. How can I change that to `ctrl + space` ?

Answer (score 4):

Most terminal emulators — and the programs that run in them — don't recognize `<C-Space>` as `<C-Space>` at all. Vim gets a NULL, also noted `<C-@>` instead and simply acts as if you actually typed `<C-@>` which is an insert mode command that inserts the last inserted text.

So, basically, you can't map `<C-Space>`.

What you can do, though, is map `<C-@>`:

```
 inoremap <C-@> <C-p>
```